# Where can I see the content of submit() java script function?

Tags: javascript, function, submit

Just for curiosity... If possible, where can I find and see the javascript submit() function's content on the form? Just to see how it handles http requests.

thanks!

Comment: It's implemented natively by the browser, I guess you can look into Firefox's source files but I don't know where it would be - Firefox's codebase is pretty huge.

Comment: Do you mean the "function" called by the browser to submit the form when the user clicks the submit button? That "function" is native code, so you cannot see it. What http request do you want to learn more about?

Comment: Yes; the function called by __doPostback function to submit the form.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a native code built-into your browser.

If you are using Firefox, you can see the code for any function by using `alert(func.toSource())` yet Firefox won't reveal the code for submit().

Try typing this in the location box of your Firefox on any webpage that has at least one form on it (e.g. this very page): `javascript: alert(document.forms[0].submit.toSource())` to see what I mean ;)

Comment: Yes, it returns Function submit(){ [nativeCode] }; :)

Answer (score 2):

The submit() function is not in JS anymore, it's built into the browser. So, short of hooking into the browser process with a debugger, you can't see the execution as it goes into submit() and gets transformed into a HTTP request.

However, if you want to see the HTTP request (and response), use some sort of capturing proxy, like [EricLaw's excellent Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/) (this should be sufficient, but should you wish to inspect the lower layers (TCP,IP), you can capture the data using [Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/))

Answer (score 1):

Javascript submit just submits the value of the forms into the page you specified  in the action parameter of the form. So u can get those data from that page .ie, the page in the action parameter.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend using Firebug's Net panel. It shows you headers, post, response